# Enter needs to be pressed twice after inserting text - C

Tags: c, input, console-application

I'm trying to get a multiple-line text at once from user and process it line-by-line but after inserting from clipboard to the console, ENTER needs to be pressed twice to send and continue.
Expected behavior: CTRL+V then ENTER executes program.
Actual behavior: CTRL+V inserts text, ENTER begins new line, and 2nd ENTER sends text.

Function that handles input:

```
char* getNewLine(bool* finish){
    char* string;
    string = malloc(sizeof(char));
    string[0]='\0';
    int c;
    int i = 0;

    while( (c = getchar()) != '\n'){
        string = realloc(string, sizeof(char)*(i+2));
        string[i] = (char)c;
        string[i+1] = '\0';
        i++;
    }

    if(i == 0){                         //if last line was empty, stop while loop in main
        *finish = true;
    }

    return string;
}
```

Main program:

```
int main(){

    bool finish = false;
    int line_count = 0;                //Number of lines found
    int good_count = 0;                //Lines matches

    char* line;

    while(!finish){                    //Read console line-by-line
        line = getNewLine(&finish);
        if(!finish){
           if(checkString(line)){      //checkString returns true, if string matches some conditions
              good_count++;
           }
        line_count++;
        }
        free(line);
    }

    printf("%d/%d\n", line_count, good_count); 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `main` code has a loop that repeatedly reads input lines until you input a blank line.  So you'll need to input a blank line to end that loop and finish the program.  If your cut-n-paste text does not include an empty line, you'll need to enter one -- so if your cut-n-paste is not complete lines, after the ctrl-V, you'll need to hit enter to end the last line of the paste, then enter again to input a blank line an exit the loop.

Comment: What is the best way to correct? Since user won't press Ctrl + Z, I can't wait for EOF. How can I differentiate '\n' and ENTER?

Comment: You can't as long as you are using a terminal -- they're the same as far as the terminal is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be an issue on my pc (debian).

If you try to substitute your code

```
if(checkString(line)){
    good_count++;
}
```

with

```
printf("line: %s\n",line);
```

you will see that the code is parsed after you press enter, at least it does so on linux.
There can be two possible reason for that problem:

1. you are using Windows, so you need to check for '\r\n' instead of '\n'.
2. you are try to use this program with only one line, the output will be printed only if you press the empty line, so you need to give the first \n to parse the Ctrl+V and the second to exit the program. In this case your program works fine.

Hope this help